# No network after Windows crash

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

Windows 7 crashed on my Toshiba Satellite Pro s500. Following reboot, neither the LAN card nor the wireless cards work anymore. The LAN card appears on the Device Manager, but not on the Network connections or the taskbar. The wireless wizards appears but can't connect to any network. I tried disabling and then uninstalling/installing the cards from the Device Manager, but they still don't work. When I connect the LAN card to the ethernet network, there is a green and blinking orange light. Are both cards dead? How can I troubleshoot them?

[image: Network Connections]
[image: Device Manager]

Comment: Does the wireless network card show available networks?  if so, then your adapter is working.  It looks like your wired adapter is disabled.  Right Click on it and select "Enable" should fix that... Though I suspect you tried both of these already.

Comment: yes the wireless shows networks but can't connect to any network..the disabled one is the vpn adapter..the ethernet adapter doesn't even show up